# Ionic angular Safe-area css ios issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic v6.2 angular 14 app and this is my android and ios view:
ANDROID:
[image]

IOS:
[image: image image 934×2043 92.3 KB]
This is my code:

```
<ion-content *ngIf="(currentUser$ | async) as currentUser" class="page">
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar mode="ios" color="primary">
      <ion-title>{{currentUser.profile_name}}</ion-title>
      <ion-button slot="end" id="parameters-button" (click)="onGoToParameters()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <div class="sub_header">
</div>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see, my ion-header is under/overlay by the statusbar and the notch.
I have tried --ion-safe-area-top but it seems equal to 0 with iphone13…
If someone has a answer… please :cry:

Comment: I faced the same issue when I try ionic react. The solution was, Go to the `public folder > index.html` and add `viewport-fit=cover` in the metatag. see the updated tag here" <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="`viewport-fit=cover`, width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    />

Answer (score 1):

You must set `viewport-fit=cover` in your html meta tag. [This css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/the-notch-and-css/) explains a bit.

Here is my full meta tag:

```html
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
/>
```

I am using vite and I added this in src > index.html inside the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
body {
  margin-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
  margin-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
ion-tab-bar {
  margin-bottom: calc(4px + env(safe-area-inset-top));
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/964